# Make StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ sync unread count across sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button

Currently, the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ shows the unread items count across all open SE sites when they are refreshed, so if I receive a new notification and I navigate to a different page on multiple SE sites before I view it, they will all get a red circle. But after I read the notification, by opening the  StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ on one site, and clicking on the link, I still see the red circle in every other site. Would it be possible to sync unread items across all open sites?

*Edited*: Unread counts do not appear instantaneously, but on refreshing the page.

Comment: You don't still see the red circle after you *refresh* the page. Are you suggesting that we somehow *dynamically* refresh the MultiCollider SuperDropdown on *all of your open pages*? I don't think I support this...

Comment: @Cody I did *not* notice that. I see that it is indeed the case. But yes, dynamic refreshing would be nice. Why exactly do you have a problem with that?

Comment: Seems like a fairly big overhead (either polling or long requests) for just a visual thing

Comment: It clearly polls **before** it turns red.  Does it **stop** polling once it turns red?  I don't know if I've waited long enough to see.

Comment: @Rick: It stops polling once you've loaded the page... It only polls again if you reload the page, or click on the drop-down.